# Внесение внутреностей файла в переменную

Tags: php

Появилась проблема, есть цикл:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$result_rows; $i++) {
$tabview .= include('parts/tabview.php');
$blockview .= include('parts/blockview.php');
}
```

Который должен добавлять результат включения в переменную. Но он сразу выводит  эти блоки. Оба файла представляют из себя шаблоны для вывода данных, и содержат много php, . Как можно ввести результат работы в эти переменные?

Comment: Использовать шаблонизатор.

Answer (score 1):

```
ob_start();
$myvar = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

А в Вашем варианте:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$result_rows; $i++) {
  ob_start();
  include('parts/tabview.php');
  $tabview = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  ob_start();
  include('parts/blockview.php');
  $blockview = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
}
```